# Python Azure Service Bus Identify sending device

Tags: python, azure-eventhub, azure-servicebus-queues

I want to monitor telemetry data from my devices and send then notify me when a certain order of messages arrives.

I can do this with the event bus SDK but i need to connect to all partitions as I don't know which partition the message will arrive in and assuming partition numbers will grew as more devices get connected it seems quite slow and cumbersome.

```
ReadMessage = True
try:
    timeout = time.time() + 60 #60second timer
    while ReadMessage and time.time() < timeout:
        for key in receivers:
            receive = receivers[key] #list of client objects to different partitions
            for event_data in receive.receive(timeout=1):
                meta = event_data.application_properties
                DevId = b'iothub-connection-device-id'
                messageType = b'messageType'
                currentDevice = event_data.message.annotations[DevId].decode('UTF-8')
                output_dict = event_data.body_as_json()
                if meta:
                    new_list = { key.decode(): val.decode() for key, val in meta.items() }
                    for key, val in new_list.items():
                        if key == 'messageType' and val == 'Message_I_Want'):
                            ReadMessage = False
                            #add to my list  device-id and message_i_want
                            break
        time.sleep(0.01)

    return #list of messages and deviceids
except Exception as ex:
    print ( "Unexpected error {0}" % ex )
    return
```

I have tried listening to the message routing endpoint using the QueueClient
`get_receiver()`. I can see the messages coming in but I cant identify what device has sent the message. Ideally this would be a faster way to do this as i only have to open connection.

So I guess the question is can the device id be gotten from the service bus?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Andrea, missed that one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well i didn't resolve the service bus question but I did make the event hub function a lot quicker by using asynchronous tasks.